# How to backup iPhone to iTunes for the first time (data stored on the iPhone, not on iTunes)

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, backup

I've upgraded to Lion OS X on my MacBook a while ago, but never connected my iPhone to iTunes for quite some time, however, there is no backup data on my iTunes but my iPhone has everything I need it to be transferred and backed up to my iTunes, but I cannot do this because I wanted to sync my iPhone, iTunes gave me a warning:

[image]

If I click "Sync Apps", will my iPhone apps be wiped off? Thus, causing no backup data to my iTunes.

How can I transfer my iPhone data to my iTunes without iTunes wiping my iPhone with no apps stored on iTunes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you do a direct sync, your apps will be wiped out. You should transfer the apps to the new iTunes by doing this:

> `Files` -> `Transfer Purchases from iPod`

This step should transfer your apps to iTunes. You can also see this [Apple.SE post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6224/iphone-to-itunes-application-transfer) for a similar situation. After transfering purchases, you should then be able to sync with the new iTunes without losing your apps. The same situation holds for music.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, how can I do this with unpurchased songs such as ripped from CD, downloaded from 3rd party sites?

Comment: There are a few ways. One is to transfer these songs from your original computer's iTunes library to the new Machine's iTunes library, either through Home Sharing or by copying the files manually and then importing. If that's not possible, google for iphone mp3 transfer program - there are a bunch of apps out there that can transfer from iPhone. One trialware example is http://www.mp4converter.net/iphone-transfer.html (I've never used it though). Another Apple.SE post covers this in more detail (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4667/getting-my-music-from-iphone-to-macbook).